# preg_match_all is not working or showing result

Tags: php, function, preg-match, preg-match-all

`{"popUp":false,"token":"NS2938f08ubjk765vhjJBKJB78vhjeec1_m1_7"}` 
This is curl response in JSON, and i want to extract token from this JSON response.

i used preg_match_all function but its showing null

here is my code

```
preg_match_all('/^"token":"\s*([^;]*)/mi', $result, $matches);
$token = array();
foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
    parse_str($item, $newtkn);
    $token = array_merge($token, $newtkn);
}
var_dump($newtkn)
```

i want to store that token in $newtkn variable and echo it on the screen how do i do that ?

Comment: Try `preg_match_all('/"token":"([^"]*)"/mi', $result, $matches)`. `^` at the beginning of your preg means that string should start from `"token"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably way easier to use [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) as it follows:

```
$result = '{"popUp":false,"token":"NS2938f08ubjk765vhjJBKJB78vhjeec1_m1_7"}';

$arr = json_decode($result, true);

$newtkn = $arr['token'];

echo $newtkn; //NS2938f08ubjk765vhjJBKJB78vhjeec1_m1_7
```

Or if you prefer an oriented object answer:

```
$result = '{"popUp":false,"token":"NS2938f08ubjk765vhjJBKJB78vhjeec1_m1_7"}';

$obj = json_decode($result);

$newtkn = $obj->token;

echo $newtkn; //NS2938f08ubjk765vhjJBKJB78vhjeec1_m1_7
```